# Julia Kristeva's idea about abjection and aesthetics

Tags: aesthetics, art

Can any body explain what Julia Kristeva means in the text below? Can anybody write it in more understandable plain English?

Text:

In a world in which the Other has collapsed, the aesthetic task -a descent into the foundations of the symbolic construct- amounts to retracing the fragile limits of the speaking being, closest to its dawn, to the bortomless “primacy” constituted by primal repression. Through that experience, which is nevertheless managed by the Other, “subject” and “object” push each other away confront each other, collapse, and start again-inseparable, contaminated, condemned, at the boundary of what is assimilable, thinkable: abject ([The Portable Kristeva By Julia Kristeva](https://books.google.de/books?id=0jb5x7Kl_90C&pg=PA243&lpg=PA243&dq=%22Other%20has%20collapsed,%20the%20aesthetic%20task%22&source=bl&ots=H1dWNuE9_5&sig=ACfU3U3qhRH-M3oP-mxjGCJ3Bs1aI6eHLg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqsMOX2YfoAhUjolwKHY9PD7kQ6AEwBXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Other%20has%20collapsed%2C%20the%20aesthetic%20task%22&f=false)).